# My kafka stream application does not work with docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka cluster and when I run my jar on it, it works correctly but if I created a docker with my jar, docker creation is done correctly but when i launch it, it doesnt work at all:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ./run_jar.sh ./*.jar ./
RUN chmod +x ./run_jar.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./run_jar.sh"]
```

I did the following actions

```
docker build -t kafkapp:0.1 .
docker run --rm --name consumer-1 -it kafkapp:0.1
```

here my stream kafka

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Properties

import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.{Consumed, Printed, Produced}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala._
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KStream
import org.apache.kafka.streams.{KafkaStreams, StreamsConfig}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._


object CustumerAvroStream extends App {

    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1")
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-connect")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer")
//  props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")

     val config = Map("schema.registry.url" -> "http://localhost:8081").asJava

    implicit def stringSerde = Serdes.String()
    val avroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde {configure(config, false)}
    implicit val consumer = Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String, avroSerde)
    implicit  val producer = Produced.`with`(Serdes.String, avroSerde)

    val builder = new StreamsBuilder()

    val personStream: KStream[String, GenericRecord] = builder.stream("topicperson")

    personStream.to("personSink")


    val sysout = Printed
        .toSysOut[String, GenericRecord]
        .withLabel("customerStream")
    personStream.print(sysout)


    val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props)

    streams.cleanUp()

    streams.start()

    // Add shutdown hook to respond to SIGTERM and gracefully close Kafka Streams
    sys.ShutdownHookThread {
        streams.close(Duration.ofSeconds(5))

    }

}
```

Could you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: Please show your Kafka Streams code.

Comment: Firstly, you probably need to expose some ports for Kafka. I've used `RabbitMQ`, so Im just guessing ports and authentication is required. In RabbitMQ you can use the guest creds to log in to localhost. But anything requires a different username and password. Secondly, If you `docker run -it --rm --name consumer-1 -it kafkapp:0.1 /bin/bash` you can log in to your docker and have a look around and see if everything is where it's suppose to be. Have a look, then let me know!

Comment: Also, why not just use [this](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker)? Not sure what `run_jar.sh` is but your Dockerfile seems quite minimal with 0 dependencies.

Comment: Note also that the line `RUN mkdir -p /opt/app` is unneeded (because `WORKDIR /opt/app` can be viewed as a Dockerfile equivalent of `mkdir -p /opt/app && cd /opt/app`)

Comment: @DuDoff This question sounds like he's trying to run a Kafka consumer (client, that reads messages from a topic) rather than a broker (server) so publishing ports shouldn't be necessary.